# Disabling and greying out all the contents of a dojo grid

Tags: dojo

Well, my application requires me to disable the entire grid , on a button click.

I tried to use

var grid = dijit.byId('myGrid');
grid .set('disabled',true); , but it's not working.

I basically need to 'grey out' all the contents of the grid , so that the user cannot select any row.  Thus, just changing the CSS doesn't help me.

Please reply.

Thanks,
Sonia

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know, but I have a rather ghastly way to do it myself. I create a partly transparent overlay over the grid when it's disabled.

So I'll have this CSS:

```
.gridOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}
.disabledGrid { color: #DDD; }
.disabledGrid .gridOverlay { display: block;  }
```

And my button's click event will be something like this:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("btn"), "onclick", function()
{
    //dojo.byId, not dijit.byId, to get the outer DOM node
    var grid = dojo.byId("myGrid");
    if(!dojo.query(".gridOverlay", grid).length)
    {
        dojo.create("div", {"class": "gridOverlay"}, grid);
    }
    dojo.toggleClass(grid, "disabledGrid");
});
```

Like I said, ghastly, but for my use it actually did the trick. YMMV :)

Comment: Well this "ghastly" way of doing it inspired me to write a great Widget that does exactly that, very neatly... thank you! http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Greying-out-a-form-or-a-whole-div-if-initial-data-cannot-be-fetched-td3991938.html#a3992042